# If a turing machine can't solve the halting problem for a machine X, does this imply that X is at least as powerful as a turing machine?

Tags: halting-problem, turing-completeness

Say I have a deterministic machine X, and I prove that a turing machine can't solve the halting problem for this machine when given a certain input. Does this imply that this machine X is turing-complete or more powerful than turing-complete, or is it possible for X to be less powerful than a turing machine?

Comment: This question misses a key logical point. Classically speaking every Turing machine either halts or loops so for any specific Turing machine $M$ you can always write another Turing machine that always accepts or always rejects $H$ and thus $H$ will accept IFF $M$ halts.

Comment: I think a good first step would be to formalize your problem. Here is an attempt. We can think of $X$ as a partial function $X(n,w) \to \{0,1\}$, where $n$ is the index (encoding) of the machine, and $w$ is the input. The undecidable problem is "$X(n,w) \neq \bot$". You can define the family of languages decidable and recognizable by $X$ in the usual way. You want to know whether these must contain all Turing-decidable and Turing-recognizable languages. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Of course, this definition is not very satisfying, and it is very easy to come up with counterexamples to your claim. For example, we could define $X(n,0\Sigma^*)=0$ and $X(n,1w) = T(n,w)$, where $T$ is the partial function corresponding to Turing machines. What is missing here is some sort of closure under reductions. Arbitrary computable reductions are probably too strong (since any nontrivial $X$ will automatically be at least as strong as Turing machines), since you should choose a weaker class.

Comment: All of this suggests that presently the question is not well-defined, and it needs some more work on your side.